# WordPress enqueue_script doesn't work anymore

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming

After update the WordPress to 4.5.3 version, my wp_enqueue_script cannot work anymore. I tried to search inside StackOverflow and Google but without any luck.
For a test, I put a new file (test.js) inside my js folder.
In my project, jquery is not necessary, it will be include with grunt minify.

My code is:

```
function sup_theme_js () {
   wp_enqueue_script('main_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/test.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sup_theme_js');
```

PS: The css code is working.

```
function sup_theme_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/main.css', false, '1.1', 'all');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_style', 'sup_theme_css' );
```

Thanks

---

**UPDATE**

My mistake!

I thought wp_enqueue_script didn't need wp_footer to work, because of that, wp_footer() was not placed at the footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake!

I thought wp_enqueue_script didn't need wp_footer to work, because of that,  wp_footer() was not placed at the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax (with plugin_url and **FILE**).

```
function include_myscript() {
 wp_enqueue_script('custom', plugins_url( 'js/customer-script.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex, was a huge mistake of mine, I forgot to put wp_footer()!!! I thought wp_enqueue_script didn't need the wp_footer to work. ¬¬

Answer (score 0):

```
function load_my_jQuery() { 
  wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"), false);
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
  wp_register_script('blur', get_template_directory_uri() . '/_/js/blur.js', array('jquery') );
  wp_enqueue_script('blur');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_jQuery');
```